# Why is Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows 7 using a 1.9.1 path for gems? it is using c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I installed Ruby 1.9.2 using one click installer to c:\ruby192

It doesn't set any path, so I set it to include c:\ruby192 at the very beginning of the path.

But when it error on something (for Rails 3.0), the path says:

```
[Error message]
c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb
```

why is it 1.9.1 gems path for Ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [a little FAQ chapter](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215219) to the release:

> The standard library is installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1
>     This version number is "library compatibility version".  Ruby 1.9.2 is
>   mostly compatible with the 1.9.2, so its library is installed in the
>   directory.